# PHP Beginner: Is using the exec command standard practice?

Tags: php, ls

I am just starting php.  I am just curious if there is a better way to do this.  This displays all of my scripts in the same folder as this script.

I am not sure if it is standard to use the exec command.  It does not seem very portable.

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>My PHP Practice Scripts</title>
</head>

<body>
   <center><h1>PHP Scripts</h1></center>
   <?php
      exec("ls -1 *.php", $output);

      foreach ($output as &$tmp){
         echo "<a href=\"$tmp\">$tmp</a><br>";
      }
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I worked professionally for about 4 years in PHP and never once used `exec()` in production code. I'm not claiming it's *never* useful, but it certainly isn't common or standard practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are directory functions for such operations: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php

Comment: more OS neutral. Better approach.

Comment: @Visionary: I missed the point about portability. Removed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

"exec" is portable beacuse is an API! :-) What is not portable is the string that represents the command line you invoke through "exec".

In this case you can use a PHP API to read the directory. That is portable on every OS you use onto your server.

Ex: [dir class in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php)

Answer (score 1):

> Is using the exec command standard practice?

No. Using `exec` to interact with the host operating system is a very non-portable practice. For virtually any situation, there is an OS-independent solution; in this particular case, you can find all the files in the current directory with [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), [`readdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) or [`scandir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).

Using `eval` in a program that accepts any form of user input also often leads to serious security risks. Your program doesn't suffer from such risks currently, but it is also very trivial.

Comment: while it isn't part of the question, you get props for mentioning that `eval()` should never be used w/ user accessible data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a better way to do what you're after.  There's [glob](https://www.php.net/glob) or [readdir](http://us.php.net/readdir) for starters.

As far as "standard practice goes", you'll see a lot of this in PHP land.  If a developer doesn't know PHP's huge codebase very well but does know the shell they'll end up using exec and backticks (``) all over the place to get their job done. It's a standard practice that some percentage of PHP developers hate, and another percentage couldn't live without.  Get used to seeing it.